# Overcommiting CPU Resources in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Let’s assume the following scenario:

I have a cluster with 100 CPU cores and 100 Pods each having a request of 1 CPU.

If I schedule the 101st Pod if a request of 1 CPU this will no longer be schedulable, as per my understanding.

Now, further assume that I as cluster operator have observed that pods on average only consume .3 CPU in reality. It would be beneficial if scheduling further pods instances was possible.

Can I somehow apply a global correction factor that disregards CPU requests to some degree and allows me to overcommit the available resources?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the flag `spec.containers[].resources.limits.cpu` to set your desired state on a deployment.

The official docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/cpu-default-namespace/) have some examples of how to specify this in the yaml.  You can set a global default along with min/max limits:

```
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      cpu: 1000m
    defaultRequest:
      cpu: 300m
  - min:
      cpu: 300m
  - max:
      cpu: 1000m
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not at all answer my question. Might be a misunderstanding.

Comment: @Johannes: What is your question then?  The above shows how you can set a default CPU request above the minimum (i.e. over-committing).